# How to fix 'access past the end of a local variable' in c

Tags: c

I made a function that checks to see if 6 elements of an array are equal, and if they are it changes a value of a different array. It compiles, but when I run it I get a 'stack buffer overflow' and my compiler says that my array is unintialized even though I initialized it.

I tried redefining the whole array in the function but that gave and "expected expression" error.

```
int match(int numbers[], int matchHighest){
    int matchArray[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int i = 0;
    match6(&numbers[i], &matchArray[5]);

    matchHighest = matchArray[5];
    return matchHighest;

}



int match6 (int numbers[], int matchArray[5]){
    int i=0;
    matchArray[5] = 0;
    while((numbers[i]==numbers[i+1]) && (i<4)){
        i++;
    }
    if(i == 4){
        matchArray[5] = 6 * numbers[0] + 27;
    }
    return matchArray[5];
}
```

I want it to change the value of matchArray[5] if the if statement is met.

Edit:
My main is:

```
int main(void){
    int numbers[6]={0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int matchHighest = 0;
    inputArray(numbers);
    match(numbers, matchHighest);
    printf("test worked \n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please give us your main as well.

Comment: This code seems to be a bit confused about whether `matchArray` contains 5 members or 6. What are you intending here? Also, why do you call two different things `matchArray`? That's almost certainly creating serious confusion.

Comment: I meant for matchArray to have 6 members, but I wanted to change the value of the 5th element

Comment: 5th element has index 4.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `&matchArray[5]`, which is the address of the 5th element of matchArray as the `matchArray` argument of match6.  Since match's matchArray only has 6 elements, this is a slice of only 1 element, which is too small.

You probably want to pass `matchArray` -- a pointer to the 0th element, in which case you'll get a slice of all 6 elements.  Then you also probably want to declare the argument to match6 as `int matchArray[6]`

Answer (score 0):

`matchArray` is an array of 6 elements but the parameter is declared as having only 5 `int matchArray[5]`. So the assignment within the called function `matchArray[5] = 0` appears to be out of bounds given how the parameter is declared.